# I am going to be a teaching assistant for a course twice, How should I mention it on my resume under positions of responsibility?

Tags: resume

I am going to be TA for Computer Architecture Course twice. The next session is from July’16 to December ‘16. 
Currently I have written like this: “Teaching Assistant for Computer Architecture Course (taught 8085 programming using Jubin’s simulator). (Jan ’16 -May ’16)”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the additional dates in the last parentheses:

> Teaching Assistant for Computer Architecture Course (taught 8085 programming using Jubin’s simulator). (Jan-May 2016, Jul-Dec 2016)

The date formats are my own preference; write them however you prefer.  It doesn't matter as long as it is clear.

Comment: And the only reason I can think that you wouldn't write "Jan-Dec 2016" is that it would include Summer semesters.

Comment: @Zibbobz No, I'd recommend at least making two entries for dates.  That makes it clear there were two sessions.

Comment: Or three, if you theoretically did in fact teach Summer courses as well?